# Array suddenly not working

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, sas, sas-studio

I have been working with an array which has been working fine until the most recent update to the data. An example dataset can be constructed as follows:

```
Data Have;
    input Fixed_or_floating $ ID Vintage Base2017 Base2018 Base2019 Base2020 dateoflastrepricing repricingfrequency;
    datalines;

      FLT    1    2017    0    0      0      0      2011    2
      FLT    1    2018    0    0      0      0      2011    2
      FLT    1    2019    0    0      0      0      2011    2
      FLT    1    2020    0    0      0      0      2011    2
      FLT    2    2017    0    0      0.1    0.1    2014    1
      FLT    2    2018    0    0      0.1    0.1    2014    1
      FLT    2    2019    0    0      0.1    0.1    2014    1
      FLT    2    2020    0    0      0.1    0.1    2014    1

      FIX    3    2017    0.1  0.3    0.2    0.1    2016    3
      FIX    3    2018    0.1  0.3    0.2    0.1    2016    3
      FIX    3    2019    0.1  0.3    0.2    0.1    2016    3
      FIX    3    2020    0.1  0.3    0.2    0.1    2016    3
      FLT    4    2017    0    0      0.1    0      2016    1
      FLT    4    2018    0    0      0.1    0      2017    1
      FLT    4    2019    0    0      0.1    0      2017    1
      FLT    4    2020    0    0      0.1    0      2017    1

;
run;
```

The object is to create an array which puts a flag=1 when the vintage is equal to the base year (dependent on some restrictions) as such:

for a fixed asset it's easy, the flag just needs to = 1 when the vintage year = the base year

```
Flag2017    Flag2018    Flag2019    Flag2020
1           0           0           0
0           1           0           0
0           0           0           1
```

for floating the flag=1 when it is repriced on that year. So for example, if the last repricing was in 2011 and it is repriced every two years, it is repriced on 2011, 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019, 2021. Then for 2018, it's repriced in 2 years time. Then for 2019, repriced in 2 years time. I am only flagging years 2017-2020 so I'd look for a table like this

```
Vintage  Flag2017    Flag2018    Flag2019    Flag2020
2017     1           0           1           0
2018     0           0           0           1
2019     0           0           0           0
2020     0           0           0           0
```

The code I used to use is:

```
data want;
set have;

*arrays for years and flags;
array _Base(2014:2022) Base2014-Base2022;
array _flag(2017:2022) flag2017-flag2022;

*loop over array;

if upcase(FixedorFloating)="FIX"
    then do i=2017 to 2020;
        /*check if year matches year in variable name*/
        if put(Vintage, 4.) = compress(vname(_Base(i)),, 'kd') 
            then _flag(i)=1;
    end;

else if upcase(fixedorfloating)="FLT" and repricingfrequency=2
    then do i=2017 to 2020;
        if put(Vintage, 4.) = compress(vname(_Base(i)),, 'kd')
            then _flag(i)=1;
        else if put(Vintage, 4.) = compress(vname(_Base(i-2)),, 'kd') 
            then _flag(i)=1;
    end;

else if upcase(fixedorfloating)="FLT" and repricingfrequency=1  
    then do i=2017 to 2020;
        if put(Vintage, 4.) <= compress(vname(_Base(i)),, 'kd')
            then _flag(i)=1;
    end;

else if upcase(fixedorfloating)="FLT" and repricingfrequency>=3
    then do i=2017 to 2020;
        if put(Vintage, 4.) = compress(vname(_Base(i)),, 'kd')
            then _flag(i)=1;
        else if put(Vintage, 4.) = compress(vname(_Base(i-3)),, 'kd') 
            then _flag(i)=1;
    end;

drop i;
run;
```

I have realised that I need to put in a catch for if the year is even or odd, i'll add this later. My question is why am I getting this error, the array should be large enough for the operation?

```
ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 87 column 42.
 87           if put(Vintage, 4.) = compress(vname(_Base(i)),, 'kd')
 88           then _flag(i)=1;
```

EDIT: additional log

```
 Fixed_or_floating=FLT ID=1 Vintage=2017 Base2017=0 Base2018=0 Base2019=0 Base2020=0
 dateoflastrepricing=2011 repricingfrequency=2 Base2014=. Base2015=. Base2016=. Base2021=.
 Base2022=. flag2014=. flag2015=. flag2016=. flag2017=. flag2018=. flag2019=. flag2020=. flag2021=.
 flag2022=. i=2017 _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
```

Comment: I think there is some interesting part of your log missing in your post, including things like `Base2014=` _some value_ and `ERROR=1`

Comment: Sure, i'll add that one in just a sec

Comment: It seems that there isn't a base 2017 ? very strange. Edit: I see it

Comment: The code you posted works (after fixing one variable name). I would look up in the program for missing semi-colon or something else that is causing it to be  running a different data step than you think.

Comment: @tom - I found it really strange that the code worked after removing the else if, I'll check over it again and see if I can put the else if back

Answer (score 0):

How strange, if I remove the "else if" and replace with an "If" then it works.